# Is this a deadlock when using ReentrantReadWriteLock?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have an application with 1 writer thread and 8 reader threads accessing a shared resource, which is behind a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. It froze for about an hour, producing no log output and not responding to requests. This is on Java 8.

Before killing it someone took thread dumps, which look like this:

Writer thread:

```
"writer-0" #83 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f899c166800 nid=0x2b1f waiting on condition [0x00007f898d3ba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000002b8dd4ea8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$FairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$WriteLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:943)
```

Reader:

```
"reader-1" #249 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f895000c000 nid=0x33d6 waiting on condition [0x00007f898edcf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000002b8dd4ea8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$FairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:967)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1283)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:727)
```

This looks like a deadlock, however there are a couple of things that make me doubt that:

- I can't find another thread that could possibly be holding the same lock
- Taking a thread dump 4 seconds later yealds the same result, but all threads now report `parking to wait for  <0x00000002a7daa878>`, which is different than `0x00000002b8dd4ea8` in the first dump.

Is this a deadlock? I see that there is *some* change in the threads' state, but it could only be internal to the lock implementation. What else could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @lucumt it's pretty much calling `rwl.readLock().lock()` and executing code in a `try-finally` with releasing the lock in the `finally` block. The same for the write lock.

Comment: Try running `jstack -l` against the process it attempts to find and report Java level deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks @JamesMudd, It was run like this. There are no relevant locked objects in either `- locked` or `Locked ownable synchronizers:` parts of the stacktraces, just IO stuff.

Comment: What operating system the application is running on? Do you have any call to thread.sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was a deadlock. The thread holding the lock was not reported as holding any locks in the thread dump, which made it difficult to diagnose.

The only way to understand that was to inspect a heap dump of the application. For those interested in how, here's the process step-by-step:

1. A heap dump was taken at roughly the same time as the thread dumps.
2. I opened it using Java VisualVM, which comes with JDK.
3. In the "Classes" view I filtered by the class name of the class that contains the lock as a field.
4. I double-clicked on the class to be taken to the "Instances" view
5. Thankfully, there were only a few instances of that class, so I was able to find the one that was causing problems.
6. I inspected the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` object kept in a field in the class. In particular the `sync` field of that lock keeps its state - in this case it was `ReentrantReadWriteLock$FairSync`.
7. The `state` property of it was `65536`. This represents both the number of shared and exclusive holds of the lock. The shared holds count is stored in the first 16 bits of the state, and is retrieved as `state >>> 16`. The exclusive holds count is in the last 16 bits, and is retrieved as `state & ((1 << 16) - 1)`. From this we can see that there's 1 shared hold and 0 exclusive holds on the lock.
8. You can see the threads waiting for the lock in the `head` field. It is a queue, with `thread` containing the waiting thread, and `next` containing the next node in the queue. Going through it I found the `writer-0` and 7 of the 8 `reader-n` threads, confirming what we know from the thread dump.
9. The `firstReader` field of the sync object contains the thread that have acquired the read log - from the comment in the code `firstReader is the first thread to have acquired the read lock. firstReaderHoldCount is firstReader's hold count.More precisely, firstReader is the unique thread that last changed the shared count from 0 to 1, and has not released theread lock since then; null if there is no such thread.`

In this case the thread holding the lock was one of the `reader` threads. It was blocked on something entirely different, which would have required one of the other `reader` threads to progress. Ultimately it was caused by a bug, in which a reader thread would not properly release the lock, and keep it forever. That I found by analyzing the code, and adding tracking and logging when the lock was acquired and released.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a deadlock?

I don't think this is evidence of a *deadlock*.  At least, not in the classic sense of the term.

The stack dump shows two threads waiting on the same `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.  One thread is waiting to acquire the read lock.  The other is waiting to acquire the write lock.

Now if no threads currently holds any locks, then one of these threads would be able to proceed.

If some other thread currently held the write lock, that would be sufficient to block both of these threads.  But that isn't a deadlock.  It would only be a deadlock if that third thread was *itself* waiting on a different lock ... and there was a circularity in the blocking.

So what about the possibility of these two threads blocking each other?  I don't think that is possible.  The reentrancy rules in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) allow a thread that has the write lock to acquire the read lock *without blocking*.  Likewise it can acquire the write lock it it already holds it.

The other piece of evidence is that things have changed in the thread dump you took a bit later.  If there was a genuine deadlock, there would be no change.

---

If it is not a deadlock between (just) these two threads, what else could it be?

One possibility is that a third thread is holding the write lock (for a long time) and that is gumming things up.  Just too much contention on this readwrite lock.

If the (assumed) third thread is using `tryLock`, it is possible that you have a *livelock* ... which could explain the "change" evidence.  But on the flip-side, that thread should have been parked too ... which you say that you don't see.

Another possibility is that you have too many active threads ... and the OS is struggling to schedule them to cores.

But this is all speculation.